# Как обеспечить наложение картинки на границу областей в Opera?

Tags: html, css

Есть следующая разметка (http://jsfiddle.net/CTZsd/). В Chrome, Firefox, IE 9 картинка накладывается на смену фона правильно, то есть картинка расположена и на черном, и на белом. А в Opera картинка расположена целиком на черном, а белый идет уже ниже (что не правильно).

Как сделать так, чтобы картинка и в Opera располагалась и на черном, и на белом, то есть чтобы блок с белым фоном не съезжал вниз под картинку.

Спасибо.

---

Правильно (Chrome, Firefox, IE 9).

[image]

Неправильно (Opera).

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html />
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: black;
        }
        header {
            font-size: 48px;
            margin: 75px auto 0 auto;
            width: 800;
        }
        #contents {
            padding: 30 0;
            background-color: white;
        }
        header h1 {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-size: 48px;
            font-weight: normal;
        }
        #intro {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 800;
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <img style="float: right; margin: 0 0 60 60;" src="http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/6114/98484902.1b/0_7d838_2c2146e_M.jpg" />
            <h1>Some text</h1>
        </header>
        <section id="contents">
            <section id="intro">
                <p>Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here.</p>
                <p>Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here.</p>
                <p>Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here.</p>
            </section>
        </section>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Проверил в FF v13.0.1, Opera v12.00 (1467), Safari v5.1.7 (7534.57.2), Chrome 20.0.1132.47m и Осле v9. Во всех этих браузерах отображается нормально и как вы задумывали. А в Осле ниже девятой - естественно, что нет, т.к. элементы HTML5 они не поддерживают.

Почему у вас в Опере верстка едет не знаю, но может версия старовата.

Comment: Спасибо! Я тестирую в Opera v12.00 (1467). Если смотреть в jsfidle, то все в порядке. Но если вставить и сохранить приведенный код вотдельный файл и открыть его в браузере, то проблема проявится.

Comment: Наверно, я вас огорчу, т.к. в отдельном файле [выглядит так же нормально](http://i.piccy.info/i7/70c02c83697f25b55df65a74decd06ce/1-8-543/11188845/in_opera.jpg). Попробуйте очистить кэш.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё дело в том, что, уж извините, Вы написали код чёрти как.

Видимо все браузеры кроме оперы умеют не сильно придерживаться стандартов, вот почему так и выходит. Пишите правильно и будет всё хорошо, везде.

Раз уж используете HTML, а не XHTML закрытие одиночных тегов не требуется.

```
<!DOCTYPE html/>
```

Такой заголовка не существует.

Везде кроме как при написании нуля нужно указывать, в чём измеряете.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        body {
            background: black;
        }
        header {
            font-size: 48px;
            margin: 75px auto 0 auto;
            width: 800px;
        }
        header img{
            float: right;
            margin: 0 0 60px 60px;
        }
        #contents {
            padding: 30px 0;
            background: white;
        }
        header h1 {
            color: #FFF;
            font-size: 48px;
            font-weight: normal;
        }
        #intro {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 800px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <img src="http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/6114/98484902.1b/0_7d838_2c2146e_M.jpg" />
            <h1>Some text</h1>
        </header>
        <section id="contents">
            <section id="intro">
                <p>Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here.</p>
                <p>Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here.</p>
                <p>Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here. Some text is going here.</p>
            </section>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: @PavelMayorov не нашёл, дайте ссылку на подтверждение данного утверждения

Comment: @PavelMayorov остряк я смотрю. ни одного слова про закрывающийся тег там нету и ссылка то, не первоисточник вообще. а писать вы можете что угодно, для браузеров много что является "корректным". [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-doctype)

Comment: @PavelMayorov вот и отлично ведь. главное разобрали отсутствие проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

У меня Opera 11.50:
[image: Скриншот]
Как видите (чучуть обрезал скриншот но думаю суть не изменилась) всё вроде как надо...